# How do I fix "SpecVersionNeedsToIncrease" error?

Tags: polkadot, storage, migration

I Just clone this https://github.com/OAK-Foundation/substrate-node-template/tree/nicks-v2 for storage migration. After launch on polkadot ,this error shows:[image]

I'm using following commands to run:

1. ./target/release/node-template --dev
2. cp target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/node_template_runtime.wasm upgrade2.compact.wasm  **(upload this file in Developer > Sudo, system.setCode)**
   For submitting Above file it shows **SpecVersionNeedsToIncrease**, However I increase the version many times 100 -> 101 -> 102 -> 103...

Upload types.json contain this code :
{
"Nickname": {
"first": "Vec",
"last": "Option<Vec>"
},
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Increment [spec_version in the code](https://github.com/OAK-Foundation/substrate-node-template/blob/4205bb08cdec6a3cba6ab287f311ce913a9480b0/runtime/src/lib.rs#L101), rebuild the WASM and perform the upgrade.

When upgrading the check will be done on the actual WASM blob to ensure that the version has been increased. (This is the check the error comes from)